# Will router.navigate() change router url instantaniously

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to see if navigate function will change the router url right after executing.

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/products']);
if (this.router.url.includes('/home/products'))
  console.log('changed');
```

Comment: Yes, the router.navigate() function will change the router URL immediately after executing. It performs a navigation operation and updates the browser's URL accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DanielVágner. But for me there is a delay. it is not getting updated right there. it takes couple of other code executions to complete before it happens. If there are some other lines after navigate() function, will it wait for all of that to be completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my comment to answer so I can format code in my response to your question.

It´s asynchronous, and by default, it does not wait for all other code executions to complete before the navigation takes place.

But if you want to try to execute your code after the route try async / await

```
async yourFunction() {
  await this.router.navigate(['/home/products']);
  // Code to execute after navigation is complete
}
```

or  then

```
this.router.navigate(['/home/products'])
  .then(() => {
    // Code to execute after navigation is complete
  });
```

Like this it will wait till navigation is completed and execute the code after that.